# Can't find out base GitLab API base url

Tags: api, gitlab

I've created project and repo on my gitlab.com account, generated private key, now I'm trying to do api call to get list of commits.

Now I want to get list of projects via api, from documentation
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-projects

```
GET /projects
```

So I'm doing

```bash
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXX -c" "https://gitlab.com/projects"
```

And getting 404.
I've tried several combinations and can't find correct base url.

Same for repository commits, documentations https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html says

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/5/repository/commits
```

fine, I'm trying (with myusername/projectname as project id)
`https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/myusername/projectname/repository/commits`

And got 404 as well

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The correct base url for the hosted GitLab is `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/` so your request to
[`GET /projects`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) would be

```bash
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects"
```

That would return all projects that are visible to you, **including other user's public projects**.

If you wish to view just your projects, then you should use the [`GET /users/:user_id/projects`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-user-projects) endpoint, where `:user_id` is your user ID that can be found on your [GitLab profile page](https://gitlab.com/-/profile) or in the response to your request to [`GET /user`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#list-current-user-for-normal-users) if you're authenticated.

```bash
# Get :user_id from this request
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user"

# See your projects by replacing :user_id with id value from previous request
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/:user_id/projects"
```

Also, the project ID is not the same as the project name. You can retrieve the project ID from the response of your request to `GET /users/:user_id/projects`, or from the project's settings page.

Comment: Is there any snippet that would translate human-seen gitlab url to api url automatically?

Comment: I tried this with my access token but it got me someone else projects

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Please check "simple" parameter in gitlab api

Comment: quite unbelievable.... that the only place I am able to find that url is in this SO answer. I have never experienced worse docs than gitlabs api documentation

Answer (score 10):

For me the following request worked:

```bash
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/YOUR_USER_ID/projects"
```

Don't know why the request :`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/"` returned a list with some other public projects.

Another useful request for user info: `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/"`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#basic-usage

try this command : curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"
as given in the document

If you are using version3 of Gitlab 
then use 
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH-TOKEN" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects

There is also "python-gitlab"  module which will help you get Id from Project-name easily
https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/